# What percentage of the Java world uses Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm building a tutorial for a Java library. There's a really easy way to get started with Maven + Eclipse, but I'm not sure I can assume the majority of the people following this tutorial will have Maven setup. So, I'm curious, what percentage of the Java world uses Maven to manage their projects?

Comment: Personally, I hate it.  I have no use for Maven at all, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I would have use for it if it wasn't such a pain to use. Good that I found Gradle, which unlike Maven, wasn't designed by masochists.

Comment: What percentage of the Java world uses Maven?
God knows, I hate Maven

Comment: A much too big percentage...  I mean, even it's 0.0001%, it would still be much too big.

Comment: Just link to maven tutorial. It's very annoying to download tons of jars with non-maven project, or figth with importing non-maven libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your library is not Maven centric i will prefer a build-tool agnostic tutorial and optional an appendix that may explain usage of your library in the specific environments (Eclipse, Netbeans, Ant, Maven, ...).

Comment: ++++++1 for documentation that is (whenever possible) tool-agnostic.

Answer (score 9):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077477/112222) other Question on SO with ton of details. Personally I like maven which helps me getting started with any project almost immediately with minimum fuss. Also maven had plugins to work with all IDE's and makes life really easy.

Comment: Find the misfit: "easy", "minimum fuss", "Maven"

Comment: Wonder about What part of Maven makes it misfit?

Comment: Also I accept that there are better tools than maven like Gradle, but comparing ant+ivy vs maven, Maven is a definite winner

Comment: Personally I think Maven has one of the steepest learning curves ever. I honestly can't see anything about Maven that is simple or easy. Even after two years I still dig up the documentation to do dead simple things such as printing something to stdout (get that: Maven cannot do anything with the command line, it requires you to configure the ant-run plugin to do that). Maven's problem is that it cannot cope with its own complexity, even if the problem at hand is trivial. Gradle instead is a beaming example of scaling complexity of use to the complexity of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the documentation isn't the best. However, maven is a life saver when trying to manage a medium to large scale project. Because of this fact of **my** life, adding an open-source library that is not on maven is a pain.

The advantage of maven is not just the auto-download of dependencies, but it also imposes a standard directory structure which means that I can script against any library we use, internal or open-source.

The biggest Maven cons:

- the very verbose command line.
- documentation is cryptic and scattered
- no universal help facility

That said, my solution to many of these issues is a custom ant build.xml file with my standard mvn goals defined as simpler ant targets ( which also allows me to add in my own help text.)

Update:

I really should say that the documentation is cryptic. Most of my experience with the typical maven developer about documentation is typified by this exchange:

Me: *"I don't understand how to do this and the code behaves very badly."*

Them: *"The suggested way to resolve this is to download the DTD in question and use a catalog resolver. See the "catalogs" property in http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validation.html"* 
( Their suggestion involves several pages with not a single complete example)

Me: *Delightful. RTFM. It would make this plugin more useful for users who do not have the time to decrypt the manual if a good example was provided for this very common usecase.*

Them: *I am sorry, but I can't follow you. The documentation of the "catalog property" (see link above) clearly shows how to configure the use of a catalog file.*

Me: *As a friend of mine, smart guy, works at google, said this:
"Yes, the documentation says exactly how to do if you know how to do it."*

Comment: One comment on the documentation of maven: I understood the way how maven plugins are documented the day I started to develop a maven plugin. Suddenly, it makes sense. :-D However, the documentation should be provided for users not for plugin developers.

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of different (corporate) Java systems, and up to half of the systems use Maven.
So, I'd say you can definitely use Maven in the example, as it is a rather common approach. Just make sure to provide a link to download the jar file as well. People using Ant or other build tools will know how what to do with it.